# Using mercurial in eclipse with linked source

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I have an android project in my eclipse workspace. However, it uses source imported from another location - I dragged the folder onto the project and selected "Link to files and folders". The sources itself exists in a mercurial repo but the project does not. How can I get eclipse to give me a team menu for mercurial sources, is it possible? (I have installed MercurialEclipse plugin) The only thing I can see it offers me is when I right click the project to create a new mercurial repo which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

The normal solution would be to reference your second set of source as a [subrepo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

But since May 2010, [issue 11871](http://www.javaforge.com/issue/11871) shows that subrepos aren't properly recognized by the [MercurialEclipse](http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE) plugin.
Its target resolution is for MercurialEclipse1.9. We are currently at MercurialEclipse1.7.1.

So the other solution would be to make a separate project, referencing directly (and only) your second set of sources, and setup a "project dependency" between your first project and your second Eclipse project.
That second project would include a second Mercurial repo and could be shared easily with MercurialEclipse.